# How to provide custom comparator for `std::multiset` without overloading `operator()`, `std::less`, `std::greater`?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, multimap, custom-compare

I want a custom comparator for the following code. However, I am not allowed to overload  `operator()`, `std::less`, `std::greater`.

I tried to achieve this using lambda but *gcc* won't allow me to use `auto` as a non-static member. Any other way to make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

class Test 
{
public:
    // bool operator () (const int lhs, const int rhs) { // not allowed
    //     return lhs > rhs;
    // };    
    using list = std::multiset<int  /*, Test*/>;
    std::map<const char*, list> scripts;
};

int main() 
{
    Test t;
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(5);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(8);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(0);

    for (auto a : t.scripts["Linux"]) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "end";
}
```

**Edit**: With lambdas

```
class Test 
{
  public:
    auto compare = [] (const int a, const int b) { return a < b;}
    using list = std::multiset<int, compare>;    //here
    std::map<const char*, list> scripts;
};
```

Error:

```
'auto' not allowed in non-static class member
 auto compare = [] (const int a, const int b) { return a < b;}
```

Comment: *"However, I cannot overload operator()"* Do you mean it didn't work, or you're not allowed to do it?

Comment: What types are you planning to compare? By the way, comparing the const char* values is not a good idea because this is just a comparison of the pointers; moreover, using the same string literal, i.e. "Linux" could actually produce two different pointers. I would recommend to use std::string as a key in std::map

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not allowed

Comment: @Dmitry Kuzminov ouh. You're right. I just threw a sample program together but thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Where is your attempt to make a lambda work? Where is this "auto" that was not allowed? (Showing what you've tried so far is a good idea if you want a more useful answer.)

Comment: I've edited the question. @JaMiT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want a custom comparator for the following code. However, I cannot
>   overload `operator()`, `std::less`, `std::greater`.

I assume that you are not allowed to overload `operator()` of the `Test` class, but could be that of other class. If so, create a internal `private` functor which overloads `operator()` and that could be part of the alias `using list = std::multiset<int, Compare>;`

```
class Test
{
private:
    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const int lhs, const int rhs) const /* noexcept */ { return lhs > rhs; }
    };

public:
    using list = std::multiset<int, Compare>;
    std::map<std::string, list> scripts;
};
```

---

> I tried to achieve these **using lambdas** but *gcc* won't allow me to use
>   auto as a non-static member. Any other way to make this work?

**Update**: After researching a while, I found a way to go which does work<sup>**†**</sup> with a lambda function.

The idea is to use the `decltype` of `std::multiset` with *custom lambda compare* as the key of the `std::map` *scripts*. In addition to that, provide a wrapper method for inserting the entries to the `CustomMultiList`.

Complete example code: **([See live](https://godbolt.org/z/LmM0c5))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

// provide a lambda compare
const auto compare = [](int lhs, int rhs) noexcept { return lhs > rhs; };

class Test
{
private:
    // make a std::multi set with custom compare function  
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> dummy{ compare };
    using CustomMultiList = decltype(dummy); // use the type for values of the map 
public:
    std::map<std::string, CustomMultiList> scripts{};
    // warper method to insert the `std::multilist` entries to the corresponding keys
    void emplace(const std::string& key, const int listEntry)
    {
        scripts.try_emplace(key, compare).first->second.emplace(listEntry);
    }
    // getter function for custom `std::multilist`
    const CustomMultiList& getValueOf(const std::string& key) const noexcept
    {
        static CustomMultiList defaultEmptyList{ compare };
        const auto iter = scripts.find(key);
        return iter != scripts.cend() ? iter->second : defaultEmptyList;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test t{};
    // 1: insert using using wrapper emplace method
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 5);
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 8);
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 0);


    for (const auto a : t.getValueOf(std::string{ "Linux" }))
    {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    // 2: insert the `CustomMultiList` directly using `std::map::emplace`
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> valueSet{ compare };
    valueSet.insert(1);
    valueSet.insert(8);
    valueSet.insert(5);
    t.scripts.emplace(std::string{ "key2" }, valueSet);

    // 3: since C++20 : use with std::map::operator[]
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(5);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(8);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**<sup>†</sup>** Until [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) lambda are not [default constructable and copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType()). But, the *[std::map::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)* does requered the *mapped_type* to be  *[copy constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible)* and *[default constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible)*. Hence the insertion to the value of the `scripts` map(i.e. to `std::multiset<int, decltype(/*lambda compare*/)>`) using subscription operator of `std::map` is only possible from from C++20.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with your approach even if you could define a lambda the way you want to. Take a look at [the `multiset` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class multiset;
```

Notice how each template parameter is a type (using the `class` keyword). Now look at how you tried to define your list:

```
using list = std::multiset<int, compare>;
                            ^      ^
                          type   value
```

The first parameter is good, but the second is a mismatch. The `Compare` parameter needs to be a type, not an object. One general way to resolve this sort of situation is to replace `compare` with `decltype(compare)`, but that seems to be not what you want (plus it is problematic for lambda types). You seem to want a default constructed `list` to use `compare` instead of merely a default constructed object of the same type.

So what you need is a class whose default constructed object implements `operator()` in a way that gives the order you want. Since we're dealing with `int`, the standard library has some ready-made types for this purpose, namely `std::less` and `std::greater`.

```
using list = std::multiset<int, std::greater<int>>;
```

> However, I cannot overload operator(), std::less, std::greater.

Hmm... this suggests that the example code may have been over-simplified, as an overload is not called for. OK, let's suppose the list is of some type that's harder to deal with, say:

```
class I { /* Internals not important for this example. */ };
using list = std::multiset<I, ???>;
```

If you are allowed to modify `I`, then the simplest approach might be to define `operator>` (or `operator<`) for objects of type `I`. Since `std::greater` (or `std::less`) uses this operator, you get the desired order from the standard template without overloading it.

If you are not allowed to modify `I`, then I think you're left with writing your own [function object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject), as this is one situation where a lambda is inadequate. Fortunately, classes implementing function objects are easy to write; lambdas have superseded them in other situations mostly because the lambda syntax tends to be more convenient.

```
struct CompareI {
    bool operator() (const I & lhs, const I & rhs) const { return /* fill this in */; }
};
using list = std::multiset<I, CompareI>;
```

While this defines an `operator()`, it is not an overload. So it should satisfy the requirements given to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function pointer of a comparison function in the constructor:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using compType=bool(*)(int lhs, int rhs);

bool custom_compare_function(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs>rhs;
}


using list = std::multiset<int,compType>;
int main() {
    list l(&custom_compare_function);
    l.insert(1);
    l.insert(4);
    l.insert(2);
    for (auto& item: l) std::cout<<item<<std::endl;
}
```

produces the output

```
$ g++ main.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
4
2
1
```

Comment: A quick question! How will I initialize the list comparator function in this case `std::map<string&, list>`? Because map will default construct if key is not present and it will initialize the comparator to null probably

Comment: @SumitDhingra Sorry you can't you can only write comparators for the first argument of map, that is the point. Please write a proper question to get any more detailed answer.

Comment: @GemTaylor @phinz    This line in answer `list l(&custom_compare_function);` initializes the multiset comparator. Correct? But if I have something like `std::map<string&, std::set<int, compType>` then how do I initialize the comparator of multiset?

Comment: You are right, in this case the map would not default construct. Assuming `map` is your map variable, you can check for existing keys by comparing `map.find(<key>)` against `map.end()`. If the key does not exist you can use `map.emplace(...)` to construct a new entry for the map with custom arguments for the constructor, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/