# Why can not we use `std::multiset` with custom compare lambda as the value of a `std::map`?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, multiset, custom-compare

This is a follow-up question of asked
[How to provide custom comparator for `std::multiset` without overloading `operator()`, `std::less`, `std::greater`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400801/custom-comparator-for-set-without-overloading-operator-stdless-stdgreate)

and I have tried to solve by the following manner.

### Basic

One can provide custom compare lambda function(since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) to the `std::multiset` of a member of a class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

const auto compare = [](int lhs, int rhs) noexcept { return lhs > rhs; };
struct Test
{
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> _set{compare};
    Test() = default;
};
```

Simple enough.

### My Situation

The member of `Test` class is

```
std::map<std::string, std::multiset<int, /* custom compare */>> scripts{};
```

I tried to use the `std::multiset` with custom

- functor `Compare` (case - 1)
- `std::greater<>`  (case - 2)
- lambda function   (case - 3)

The first two options are a success. But the case of lambda as a custom compare function it did not work. Here is the MCVC:https://godbolt.org/z/mSHi1p

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

const auto compare = [](int lhs, int rhs) noexcept { return lhs > rhs; };
class Test
{
private:
    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const int lhs, const int rhs) const noexcept { return lhs > rhs; }
    };

private:
    // std::multiset<int, Compare> dummy;                      // works fine
    // std::multiset<int, std::greater<>> dummy;               // works fine
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> dummy{ compare };    // does not work
    using CustomMultiList = decltype(dummy);

public: 
    std::map<std::string, CustomMultiList> scripts{};
};

int main()
{
    Test t{};    
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(5);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(8);
    t.scripts["Linux"].insert(0);

    for (auto a : t.scripts["Linux"]) {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error C2280 : '<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>::<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>(void)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
note: see declaration of '<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>::<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>'
note: '<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>::<lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>(void)' : function was explicitly deleted
note: while compiling class template member function 'std::multiset<int,const <lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>,std::allocator<int>>::multiset(void)'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::multiset<int,const <lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>,std::allocator<int>>::multiset(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::multiset<int,const <lambda_778ad726092eb2ad4bce2e3abb93017f>,std::allocator<int>>' being compiled
```

It sounds like I tried to default construct the passed lambda, [which is not possible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) until [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

If that the case **where has it happened**?
Is **it possible to solve this using a lambda compare function** within the scope of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) till [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It sounds like I tried to default construct the passed lambda, which
>   is not possible until [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). If that the case **where has it happened**?

**Yes**. That exactly what happened here and due to the call of [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) at the line(s)

```
t.scripts["Linux"].insert(5);
//       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's look into detail. The above call will result in a call of the following overload as the key being temporary `std::string` constructed from `const char*`.

```
T& operator[]( Key&& key );
```

Since [C++17 this is equivalent to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

```
return this->try_emplace(
    std::move(key)).first  ->  second;
//               key_type    mapped_type
//               ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                  |           |
//                  |           |
//             (std::string)  (std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)>)
//                  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                  |           |                               (default-construction meaning)
//                  |       default-construction -->   std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)>{}
//               move-construction                                                          ^^
```

where the *key_type*(i.e. temporarly constructed `std::string` from `const char*`) should be *[move constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible)*,
which happends fine.

The *mapped_type*(i.e. `std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)>`) should be *[default construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible)* ed first and that requires the compare lambda should be also default constructed. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType()):

> **ClosureType::ClosureType()**
>
> ```
> ClosureType() = delete;   (until C++14)
> ClosureType() = default;  (since C++20)(only if no captures are specified)
> ```
>
> Closure types are  **not DefaultConstructible**. Closure types have a
>   deleted (until C++14)no (since C++14) default constructor.        `(until C++20)`
>
> ---
>
> If **no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default**
>   **constructor. Otherwise, it has no default constructor** (this includes
>   the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not actually
>   capture anything).                                                `(since C++20)`

That means, default construction of lambda closure type not available in C++17(that is what the compiler error is complaining about).

On the other hand, there is no **captures are specified**(i.e. stateless lambdas)  in the `compare` lambda there and hence it can be explicitly defaulted by the compilers which support C++20 standard.

---

> Is it **possible to solve this using a lambda compare function** within
>   the scope of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) till [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)?

**Not by using `std::map::operator[]`**(as for the reason explained above), but  **Yes**, the way what @JohnZwinck's has mentioned in his answer. I would like to explain, how that works.

One of the constructors<sup>**1**</sup> of [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/multiset) provides the possibility to pass the comparator object.

```
template< class InputIt >
multiset( InputIt first, InputIt last,
          const Compare& comp = Compare(),
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The same time, the copy constructor and the move constructor for the lambda closure type have been [defaulted since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType()). That means, if we have a possibility to provide the lambda as the first argument<sup>**2**</sup>(either by copying or by moving it), it would be the **Basic** case, what showed in the question.

```
std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> dummy{ compare };            // copying
std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> dummy{ std::move(compare) }; // moving
```

Luckily, C++17 introduced the member function [std::map::try_emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)

```
template <class... Args>
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace(key_type&& k, Args&&... args);
```

by which one can pass the lambda to the above-mentioned constructors<sup>**1**</sup> of `std::multiset` as the first argument<sup>**2**</sup> like shown above. If we warp this into the member function of the `Test` class, elements could be inserted to the `CustomMultiList` (i.e. values) of the `scripts` map.

The solution would look like(same as the linked post, because I wrote that answer after I asking this question!)

### ([See Live](https://godbolt.org/z/mLG320))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

// provide a lambda compare
const auto compare = [](int lhs, int rhs) noexcept { return lhs > rhs; };

class Test
{
private:
    // make a std::multi set with custom compare function  
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> dummy{ compare };
    using CustomMultiList = decltype(dummy); // use the type for values of the map 
public:
    std::map<std::string, CustomMultiList> scripts{};
    // warper method to insert the `std::multilist` entries to the corresponding keys
    void emplace(const std::string& key, const int listEntry)
    {
        scripts.try_emplace(key, compare).first->second.emplace(listEntry);
    }
    // getter function for custom `std::multilist`
    const CustomMultiList& getValueOf(const std::string& key) const noexcept
    {
        static CustomMultiList defaultEmptyList{ compare };
        const auto iter = scripts.find(key);
        return iter != scripts.cend() ? iter->second : defaultEmptyList;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t{};
    // 1: insert using using wrapper emplace method
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 5);
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 8);
    t.emplace(std::string{ "Linux" }, 0);


    for (const auto a : t.getValueOf(std::string{ "Linux" }))
    {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    // 2: insert the `CustomMultiList` directly using `std::map::emplace`
    std::multiset<int, decltype(compare)> valueSet{ compare };
    valueSet.insert(1);
    valueSet.insert(8);
    valueSet.insert(5);
    t.scripts.emplace(std::string{ "key2" }, valueSet);

    // 3: since C++20 : use with std::map::operator[]
    // latest version of GCC has already included this change
    //t.scripts["Linux"].insert(5);
    //t.scripts["Linux"].insert(8);
    //t.scripts["Linux"].insert(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To do it in one line, you need something like this:

```
t.scripts.try_emplace("Linux", compare).first->second.insert(5);
```

This is because the lambda `compare` has to be passed to the constructor of your `multiset`.  Otherwise there's no comparison object and the `multiset` cannot be constructed.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rVb3-D

Comment: @JeJo: No, the comparator is required to construct the `multiset`.  If you don't like this, simply create a wrapper class `my_multiset` whose default constructor constructs `multiset` with `compare`.